# Westhost to WIX domain transfer

Tags: dns, subdomain, forum

Recently my organization connected our domain to WIX.  Previously we were with Westhost.  However, our email and forum were sub-directories from our Westhost account. (marinaoutrigger.org/forum) Now we get a 404 error obviously because the content doesn't exist on the WIX IP.  I created a sub-domain (forum.marianoutrigger.org) and put the original IP of our DNS host and now the index page displays, but nothing from the sub folders.

Is there any way to keep the original marinaoutrigger.org/forum or how do I get the files withing the "forum" directory to propagate through the sub-domain?

Comment: Could you clarify where your forum code is running from now? Is it part of the Wix service, do you have it hosted on another web host, or do you not currently have the previous forum application running anywhere?

Comment: A Hosts:

Host Name                      Points to
marinaoutrigger.org             23.236.62.147
mail.marinaoutrigger.org      209.236.72.19
forum.marinaoutrigger.org    209.95.48.193

Comment: @DanBowling, the forum is not part of the Wix service, it is a simple machines forum.  Files are still hosted in our Westhost service.  Since the main domain was connected to WIX, it is not currently running.  I did try and make a copy of the files in the "forum." sub domain, but it didn't bring over everything.  Sorry if this doesn't answer your question I'm learning a lot about the situation as I troubleshoot.

Comment: Dale, it looks like you've made some progress. Your forum is loading on the subdomain, though it seems like you have some URL rewriting happening. Would you like to update your question with your current .htaccess file (presuming this is Apache web server.) It looks like a tweak there could solve your issue. Your current rule looks to be too broad and probably needs to be narrowed down a bit.

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^marinaoutrigger\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.marinaoutrigger\.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.gomarinaoutrigger\.org\/" [R=301,L]

Comment: or is it this one:
#<IfModule mime_module>
#AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php7 .phtml
#</IfModule>

Comment: Dale, I'm starting to understand what's going on a bit better. It appears that you've copied your /forum directory directly into the web root. I'll write something up as an aswer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After visiting your site and using the inspector, I can see that all of your CSS and images on the forum subdomain are 404ing. If I change the URL to your new subdomain, and remove the /forum, I am getting the images and CSS to load.

Additionally, I can see that links on your forum (which display correctly on the home page) still point to your old domain (that is now hosted on Wix.) This means you have a couple seperate issues that need to be resolved.

**To keep your current setup**

At minimum, you will need to update settings for your simple machines forum to supply a new base URL. That will be required to have the forum provide links that start with your forum.marianoutrigger.org subdomain.

Ideally, this will also update your theme to point images, CSS, and links to the correct location. If not, you can utilize the mod rewrite file to strip the forum directory from requests. A rule like this is a good base to do that:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

**To reverse proxy to Wix**

Another solution you could do is have your (old) Westhost site still host your domain as it did before. Leave your forum inside /forum, and reverse-proxy other content over to the Wix site. This basically means that Westhost would keep your domain, host your /forum, and any other requests it gets it would forward to Wix, recieve the response, and transparently send that to the user.

This strategy has several advantages, such as leaving all URLs the same (an SEO benefit, and limiting your cleanup.)

[Apache has a basic example in their documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html). I've adapted it to give you a little nudge in the right direction (assuming your wix site is reachable via example.wix.com):

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/(forum)(.*)$
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}"       !-f
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}"       !-d
RewriteRule "^/(.*)" "http://example.wix.com/$1" [P]
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://example.wix.com/"
```

Note:

- the first line ensures the reverse proxy doesn't forward forum requests.
- the second and third lines ensure that if a file or directory exist on your server, they are sent instead of proxying
- the last two lines take your other traffix and forward it to example.wix.com on the back-end (e.g. apache will make the Wix request, then pass it along to the client.)

Comment: I'm leaning toward the reverse proxy to Wix.  Do I have to disconnect my domain from WIX first?  When using the mod-rewrite commands do I go through my WHM portal?  Or straight through my domain console?

Comment: Also, in the WHM panel it says that the mod_userdir is disabled.  Do I need this enabled to run the mod_rewrite?

Comment: mod_userdir is not applicable to your situation, it should remain disabled. I've not used c-panel/WHM for many years, but any way you edit the htaccess file should work. You could use SSH, FTP, or the file browser in your admin console.

Comment: As for disconnecting the domain, what really matters with that is what your DNS is pointing to for the domain. If you can afford the downtime, the easiest way to aproach the reverse proxy strategy would be to revert your DNS to what you had before, and simply use the free username.wixsite.com name wix provides. End users would never see that URL because it would be behind a reverse proxy.

Comment: So if i add your code from above to my .htaccess file and replace the "example.wix.com" with "gomdrocc.wixsite.com/mysite" is that ok.